# SSAS create a New Named Set

Tags: ssas, mdx

I was trying to create a new named set on SSAS :

```
Exists([Dim Device].[Browser Name].[Browser Name].members, [Dim Device].[Platform].&[android] )
```

When I go to excel to see many facts I have for my android browsers set I get this (see picture), the intersection failed, I should have get android on the columns labels.
[image]

Does any one can tell me where my intersection statement fails?

Comment: How is the set that you define involved in getting the query of which you show the result? What do you mean by "I should have get android on the columns labels"? I see "android" in cell C2. Sets themselves are never shown as row or column level, only the set members can be displayed. It is very difficult to understand what exactly you did, and what exactly that has to do with the picture, and what exactly you expected to be different. Please edit your question so that we understand it and have a chance to answer!

Comment: This is correct, it has returned a set of browsers browsers that run on android, It will not be showing any browsers that don't run on android